# How to click a cell in A5:A10 in "Sheet 2" and have that clicked cell value be inputted in cell C3 in "Sheet 1"

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, hyperlink

I have a workbook with two sheets, labeled `Sheet 1` and `Sheet 2`.

In `Sheet 2` I have a range `A5:A10`. I'd like to be able to click a cell in that range and have its contents be inputted into a cell in `Sheet 1`.

So the range `A5:A10` is

```
1001  

1002 

1003

1004

1005

1006
```

I would like to click on cell A6 (in `Sheet 2`), and have A6's value of 1002 be put into `Sheet 1 C3`. So that `C3` now has 1002.

So far I've been having to input the value in `Sheet 1` manually, but would like to not only hyperlink within the document, but have the C3's value change as well.

Comment: Would a dropdown menu allowing you to choose those values work for you? It might be the simplest way to go  about it

Comment: Can you settle for **double-click** ??

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I've used the data validation option with the drop down menu, but it's just as timely as manually entering the value into C3.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Yes, a double click would be an even better option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter the following event macro in the worksheet code area of `Sheet2`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim A As Range
    Set A = Range("A5:A10")

    If Intersect(Target, A) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Cancel = True
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3")
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Note that the code uses ***Sheet1*** rather than ***Sheet 1***. *(change this if you are using `Sheet 1`)*

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to **install** and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To **remove** the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

**EDIT#1:**

To allow the macro to deposit data on a protect worksheet:

1. Unprotect the Sheet
2. Unlock specific cells like **C3**
3. Re-protect the worksheet

This will allow the macro *(and the user)* to enter data on the Sheet and still protect formulas, etc.

**EDIT#2:**

To avoid copyinng the format, use this instead:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim A As Range
    Set A = Range("A5:A10")

    If Intersect(Target, A) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Cancel = True
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

To "kick-start" the routine after an error, put this macro in a **standard module** and run it:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I've enabled macros in Developer > Macro Security > Enable All Macros and Trust Access. And I've pasted it into the View Code of Sheet 2, and renamed the other sheet to Sheet1. However, when I double click on a cell in A5:A10, it just selects the cell and lets me edit it.

Comment: @LucasBassoli   try saving the workbook as **.xlsm**; then close the workbook; then re-open the **.xlsm** version.

Comment: Great it worked! However, it's important that Sheet1 be protected because it has a lot of formulas in it. In Sheet 1 the only cell that's unlocked is C3 and all the contents of Sheet1 reference C3 in their formulas. So I tried to protect Sheet1 and double click A6 in Sheet2, but it no longer updates C3. Is there any way to edit the macro code to keep from having to leave Sheet 1 unprotected?

Comment: @LucasBassoli  This is an important issue.  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Can the formatting in Sheet1 Cell C3 be fixed so that it is always for example Arial 24 bold, whereas on the Sheet2  Cell A6 is Helvetica 12 Light? Because when I double click on A6 it not only pastes the value of A6 into C3, but also the formatting that goes along with A6 (font, size, bold/light, borders, fill and color)

Comment: Occasionally the Debugger will run because C3 was accidentally left locked, but once the debugger stops running the doubleclick function no longer works. What's the procedure for "restarting" the code so that it reactivates?

Comment: @LucasBassoli  See my **EDIT#2**.